# Check if all fields are empty once button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a form at the moment which, depending on the users intention will bring run different reports. However, whenever I submit the form when no data has been inputted, I get an error message which I don't want the user to see. To fix this I would like to prevent the user from submitting the form whenever no data has been inputted.

HTML:

```
<content id="GenerateReportContent" class="col-md-4">
    @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ReportSelection", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "GenerateReportContainer" })) {
        <div class="AltFunctions">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('GenerateReportContainer').reset();" class="AltButton" id="altClearButton">Clear</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="AltButton" id="GRaltInfoButton">Info</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h1 id="GenerateReportHeader">GENERATE REPORT</h1>

        <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" value="@Model.ClientID" />

        @Html.TextBox("ClaimNo", "", new { @id = "txtGRCSelect", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Specific Claim Number..." })
        <p id="txtOptional">(optional)</p>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReportTypeOptions.First().ReportID, new SelectList(Model.ReportTypeOptions, "ReportID", "ReportName"), "Select Report", new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD", onchange = "disableFunction()" })
        <br />

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierID, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "DisplayName"), "Select Supplier Name", new { @id = "SuppNameDD", @class = "GRDropDown", disabled = true })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SupplierID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <br />

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReviewPeriodID, new SelectList(Model.ReviewPeriods, "ReviewPeriodID", "ReviewPeriodName"), "Select Review Period", new { @id = "ReviewPeriodDD", @class = "GRDropDown", disabled = true })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReviewPeriodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBox("MonthCode", "", new { @id = "txtGRC", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Month Code...", disabled = true, onchange = "submitFunction" })
            <p id="txtOptional">(optional)</p>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="GenerateReportButton" class="btn btn-default">GO</button>
    }
</content>
```

JQUERY:

```
  function disableFunction() {
            if ($("#ReportDD").val() == '0') {
                $('#SuppNameDD').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ReviewPeriodDD').prop('disabled', false);

            }
            else if ($("#ReportDD").val() == '1') {
                $('#SuppNameDD').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ReviewPeriodDD').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else if ($("#ReportDD").val() == '2') {
                $('#SuppNameDD').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ReviewPeriodDD').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else if ($("#ReportDD").val() == '3') {

                $('#ReviewPeriodDD').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#txtGRC').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        };
```

I'm completely new to JQuery and therefore am not sure what to do. I've looked into JQuery validation but not how to use it.

Comment: Can you please get HTML? Not ASP.NET?

Comment: The content you have posted is not HTML. Please post HTML version, the rendered one in your browser, not the source code in ASP.NET.

Comment: why not using mvc model validations http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why does it make a difference?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn I would like to help you with the answer, but I am not sure how the ASP.NET gives the output in HTML. Consider me as a "browser", and I don't understand ASP.NET. Else tag this question with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I appreciate the help but I don't think I can do that as there are about a thousand records in a drop down box and so it would take me too long. Sorry, thank you though

Comment: Ah!!! I see. Fine then.

Comment: @Learner I cannot use MVC model validation as I am not using a model for some of the fields in my view

Comment: @AndrewKilburn i can see there are some fields and you can add them in existing model as you used for dropdowns its always good practice to use model

Comment: and you just need to change `@Html.TextBox` to `@Html.TextBoxFor` in view and validations will work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    // validation code here, check that the inputs are not epmty
    if(!valid) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```